# A limit exists iff and only the left limit and the right limit exist and are equal to each other

Tags: real-analysis, limits

It is well known that

> $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x \to a+}f(x) = L = \lim_{x \to
>  a-}f(x)$$

Consider the function $\sqrt{.}: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$

Now, consider $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}$

We can prove this limit is equal to $0$. Indeed, let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon^2$. Then, for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ satysfying $0 < |x| < \delta$ or equivalently $0 < x < \delta$, we have $\sqrt{x} < \sqrt{\delta} = \epsilon$, which establishes the result.

However, my confusion lies in the following: the limit from the left does not seem to exist, making the above theorem untrue. Where lies my mistake?

Comment: That function is continuous _on its domain_, which (as you know) does not include negative numbers. Your "well known" theorem about left and right limits is true only when the point is interior to the domain - an unmentioned part of the hypothesis (loosely speaking, but that's the idea).

Comment: The equivalence is (only relevant and) only valid if the left and right-hand limits are defined, i.e. if $f$ is defined at least on $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon >0$.

Comment: This is frustrating. I'm reading Spivak's calculus and he doesn't make those hypotheses.

Comment: When you are considering $\lim_{x\to a,\ x\in A}f(x)$ and $a\in A$ is an isolated point of $A$, then the limit is just $f(a)$. When you do $\lim_{x\to0^-}\sqrt{x}$ you are doing $\lim_{x\to0,\ x\in\text{Dom}(\sqrt{\cdot})\cap(-\infty,0]}\sqrt{x}$, but that intersection is only $\{0\}$ therefore, the limit from the right is $\sqrt{0}$. So, all is good.

Comment: When I was undergraduate I used to prefer the notation $\lim_{x\to a,\ x\in A}$ to make it clear the set in which the $x$ is moving. It can get rid of those ambiguities in $x\to a^+$ and $x\to a^-$. The theorem should be written as $\lim_{x\to a,\ a\in\text{Dom}(f)}f(x)=L$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to a,\ x\in A\cap\text{Dom}(f)}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a,\ x\in A^{c}\text{Dom}(f)}f(x)=L$, where $A$ is any set such that $a$ is in the closure of $A\cap \text{Dom}(f)$ and of $A^c\cap \text{Dom}(f)$.

Comment: So, my example provides a counterexample to the theorem if we drop the assumption that $a$ has to be an interior point?

Comment: @Math_QED No, it doesn't. In your case $\lim_{x\to0^-}\sqrt{x}$, which is really $\lim_{x\to0,\ \text{Dom}(\sqrt{\cdot})\cap(-\infty,0]}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{0}=0$. It is just a matter of carefully checking what the limit from the left is.

Comment: But, the definition of limit says that (in this case) $x \neq 0$? So why does your interval contain that point. By the way, the condition $0 < -x < \delta$ is satisfied for all $x \in dom( \sqrt{.})$ (as there are none). So the implication $0 < -x < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| <  \epsilon$ is true for any number $L$. Something's not right

Comment: @Math_QED There is no such $\delta$. Whatever $\delta$ you pick around $0$, there will always be an $x$ in there for which $0 < -x < \delta$ is true but $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ is false, since $f(x)$ is not defined for those $x$, making that implication false.

Comment: Ah I see, but I still can't see how $\lim_{x \to 0-} \sqrt{x} = 0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, what you wrote is not well known, and is in fact not even true.

What **is** well known is the fact that

> Let $f$ be a function $\color{red}{\text{defined on some open neighborhood of $a$}}$. Then, $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x \to a+}f(x) = L = \lim_{x \to
>  a-}f(x)$$

Always read the fine print.

Comment: Spivak's book does not mention this.

Comment: @Math_QED It doesn't mention it because it is not part of the theorem. It is not necessary.

Comment: @orole That seems contradictory to me. 5xum says "read the fine print" but you say "it's not part of the theorem". To me, that implies that the "fine print" isn't in the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the limit exists in $x_0$ if and only if for all $x$ in the **domain** of the function we have$$\forall \epsilon>0\qquad,\qquad \exists \delta\qquad |x-x_0|<\delta\to |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$$and the domain of $f(x)=\sqrt x$ in $x_0=0$ is only $\{x\ge 0\}$ where only the right limit needs to exist. This also can be generalized further to higher dimensions where all limits from all valid directions in a sufficiently small neighborhood of some point over a metric space of metric $d(.,.)$ must exist and be equal i.e.$$\forall \epsilon>0\qquad,\qquad \exists \delta\qquad d(x,x_0)<\delta\to d(f(x),f(x_0))<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

You should be careful while  applying the $\varepsilon-\delta  $ definition it says. Let $a$ be **an accumulation (or limit point )** of $Dom(f)$ then $f$ is continuous at  $a$ if

$$\forall~~\varepsilon>0, \exists~\delta>0:\color{blue}{\text{for every $x\in Dom(f),$  } 0<|x-a|<\delta }\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon $$

in your case $x<0$ is not in the domain of $\sqrt{\cdot}$

And then the notion of limit from the left at $x=0$ does not apply here,

Comment: Where exactly do I wrongly apply the definition?

Comment: @Math_QED Read the last sentence

Comment: I'm not talking about continuity... Do you mean my proof that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x} = 0$ is wrong? That's the only place where I use the definition.

Comment: @Math_QED you should add that $x\in Dom(\sqrt{\cdot})$ then the issue is gone. since i  that case we cannot talk about the limit from the left. Yes your prooof is correct but don't forget the Dom(f)

Comment: I wrote $\mathbb{R}^+$, which is the domain I listed, didn't I?